# Hibernate removes child objects after session.update(parent)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a very simple parent-/child relationship between objects of type "Folder", which looks like this:

- A folder can have 0-1 parent folders.
- A folder can have 0-n child folders
  (subfolders).

So, basically, a simplified version of the Java class Folder looks like this:

```
public class Folder{
    long id;
    Set<Folder> childFolders;
    Folder parentFolder;
    String path;

    // Getter, setter and other (for this question)
    // not relevant properties omitted

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
            if (obj == null) return false;
            if (obj == this) return true;
            if (obj instanceof Folder){
                    Folder folder = (Folder)obj;
                    return folder.getPath().equals(getPath());
            }
            return false;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
            return getPath().hashCode();
    }

}
```

My simple test hierarchy looks like this:

```
  folder1
  folder2
- folder3
   subfolder3-1
```

Using Hibernate, I call:

```
session.update(folder1);
session.update(folder2);
session.update(folder3);
```

The first two calls succeed.

The last call for folder3 throws no exception BUT it removes subfolder3-1 from the internal set "childFolders" of folder3.
That means, `folder3.childFolders.size() = 0` although it was 1 before the last update call.
**Important:** In the database, folder "subfolder3-1" still exists!

How can that be?

Here is my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="test.Folder" table="FOLDERS">

        <id name="id" type="long" access="field">
            <column name="FOLDER_ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>     

        <set name="childFolders" table="FOLDERS" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="PARENT_FOLDER_ID"></key>
            <one-to-many class="test.Folder" />
        </set>

        <many-to-one name="parentFolder" column="PARENT_FOLDER_ID" />

        <property name="path" column="FOLDER_PATH" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: What do the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods in `test.Folder` look like?

Comment: @matt b I added the two method to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some more debug code and I finally found the solution: Directly before the `session.update(folder3)` call, I had a tiny hidden `folder.childFolders.clear()` call which obviously caused the issue, so the problem didn't have something to do with Hibernate at all. Just with my stupidness.
Sorry everyone for bothering and thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is in the inverse="true" attribute: inverse attributes are not saved.

Comment: Hm, setting inverse="false" didn't fix the issue. Besides that: Calling session.save(folder3) works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're establishing the link properly in the java world.

```
  folder3.getChildFolders().add(subfolder3);
  subfolder3.setParent(folder3);
  session.persist(folder3); //cascade here will save subfolder3
```

[Here is the hibernate documentation.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional)

Comment: Before I call the session.update(..) methods posted above, all folders are already persistent! So, I am calling session.update(..) on persistent folders. In order to INSERT folders into the database (for the first time), I use session.save.(folder3) (which works perfectly) instead of session.persist(folder3). Is that wrong?

Comment: In the code which initially inserts the folder into the DB, do you also add the folder to the parent (as @zmf shows above)?

Comment: @RMorrisey Yes, I do. I also printed the tree (including the id and the name of the parent) once before and once after the `session.update(folder3)` call. Before `session.update(folder3)` everything is as it should be (subfolder3-1 has an id and a reference to its parent). After the update call, subfolder3-1 is gone.

Comment: @valmar calling update() shouldn't delete that association, that would be 'weird'. after you call session.update(folder3) are the contents of the database correct? If so if you say Folder f3 = session.get(folder3); does f3.childFolders.size() == 0; ? Can you add some more code, perhaps your test where you're persisting these folders would be a good start. Your mapping looks correct to me.

Comment: I finally found the reason for the problem. Your hint of checking `folder3.childFolders.size()` pointed me to the right direction. I had a `folder3.childFolders.clear()` at a "hidden" place in the code and thus `folder3.childFolders.size()" was always 0. Thanks for your help!